# Oracle extended data types in combination with char semantics

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

There is one aspect of the extended data types introduced with Oracle 12 that I don't quite understand. The documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623) says:

> A VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2 data type with a declared size of greater than 4000 bytes, or a RAW data type with a declared size of greater than 2000 bytes, is an extended data type. Extended data type columns are stored out-of-line, leveraging Oracle's LOB technology.

According to this definition does "VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)" have "a declared size of greater than 4000 bytes" because with a multi-byte character set (e.g. ALS32UTF8) it could contain more that 4000 bytes?

Or more specific: What happens when I create a column of that type? I could think of the following possibilities:

1. It is created with an extended data type, so that the content of that column is always stored in a CLOB regardless of its size.
2. The values for that column are stored inline if they need not more than 4000 bytes, and as CLOB if they are longer.
3. It will refuse to store any values with more than 4000 bytes. To circumvent that I have to declare the column as VARCHAR2(4001 CHAR) or something similar.

Edit: The question had been marked as a duplicate of [Enter large content to oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686095/enter-large-content-to-oracle-database) for a few weeks, but I don't think it is. The other question is generally about how you can enter more than 4000 characters in a VARCHAR2 column, but I am asking a very specific question about an edge case.

Comment: "*have a declared size of greater than 4000 bytes*" - no it doesn't. Even if you specify `4000 char` it is **still** limited to 4000 **bytes**. So 3) will happen (but you can't specify `4001 Char` unless you enabled the extend string type in 12c

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know that without extended data types enabled, I am generally limited to 4000 Bytes. What I want to understand better, is Oracle's behavior with extended data types enabled.